# What is the origin of the name "Megatron"?

Tags: transformers, terminology, a-wrinkle-in-time

In *A Wrinkle in Time*, Meg's father calls her by two nicknames:  "Megaparsec" (whose meaning she explains) and also the much more opaque "Megatron."

> At last she turned to her father. "I'm—I'm sorry, Father."
>
> He took both her hands in his, bent down to her with his short-sighted eyes.  "Sorry for what, Megatron?"
>
> Tears almost came to her eyes at the gentle use of the old nickname.

I read the book around the same time (circa 1985) that *Transformers* toys became hugely popular in the United States.  At that time, the word *megatron* sounded perfectly natural to me at the time—much nicer than the longer *megaparsec*.  However, today, *megaparsec* is an ordinary word that I use on a regular basis in my work as a scientist, while *megatron* is associated only with *A Wrinkle in Time* and the proper name of a *Transformers* villain.

So where did that word come from?  The *Oxford English Dictionary* has no entry for it.  Google *N*-grams shows "megatron" and capitalized "Megatron" [first appearing in the 1940s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Megatron%2Cmegatron&year_start=1800), before picking up a great deal in the 1980s (as might be expected).  However, [another search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Megaton%2CMegatron&year_start=1900) suggests that a lot of early appearances of "Megatron" may be typos for "[Megaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent)" (meaning the measure of explosive power).

So where did this name come from?  Was L'Engle's first use of "Megatron" in 1962 essentially a mistake (and what Alexander Murry said really should have been "Megaton")?  Or was there some other source for the word, from which *A Wrinkle in Time* (and probably the *Transformers*) drew?

Comment: It might also be a riff on the Metatron.

Comment: I also suspect it could be a play on the angel מטטרון (Metatron).

Comment: The Megatron plasma betatron project  was active around the time Wrinkle was written.  I’d guess that was the inspiration.

Comment: "megatron is associated only with A Wrinkle in Time and the proper name of a Transformers villain" — [heresy!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4FQyShYuWA&t=102s)

Comment: If this was about transformers I would say portmanteau of mega and electron.

Comment: Transformers are perfectly capable of time travel; https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Time_travel

Answer (score 9):

The term '*megatron*' has been in scientific use since at least the 1940s, applied as a nickname to a particular type of [vacuum tube](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Technical_Data_Digest/FEZQAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=megatron&pg=RA10-PA64&printsec=frontcover) (mainly used in broadcast circuits) and latterly as a brand name for a [plasma-producing apparatus](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Nuclear_Science_Abstracts/w0gIrra2zK8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=megatron&pg=PA1877&printsec=frontcover)  manufactured by Megatron Ltd.

L'engle stated that she "studied physics" when she was writing *A Wrinkle in Time*, so it's likely that she would have come across these terms during her research.

> I did, indeed, study physics while I was writing Wrinkle, but I’ve
> never taken a course in physics, and surely I could not have learned
> enough, reading on my own, to make my book useful to an astronaut.
>
> <sub><sup>[Explore What You Know and Don't Know](https://www.kennedy-center.org/education/resources-for-educators/classroom-resources/media-and-interactives/media/literary-arts/calls-to-artistic-action/)</sup></sub>

Despite their disparate meanings the two words are found practically on top of each other in any reasonably detailed [physics dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vai7wiq5HIYC&pg=PA843&lpg=PA843&dq=physics%20dictionary%20megatron%20megaparsec&source=bl&ots=_Ly_g8JhYb&sig=ACfU3U2z_tqpdNRj1Zt-Rui8TUx0gqhm5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAiO3Uu9H5AhXzS0EAHXZICRUQ6AF6BAgqEAM#v=onepage&q=physics%20dictionary%20megatron%20megaparsec&f=false), such as an author might peruse when trying to come up with sciencey-sounding words starting with 'meg'.

[image]